# Remove lines from file what called from list

Tags: python, list, file

I want to remove lines from a .txt file.
i wanna make a list for string what i want to remove but the code will paste the lines as many times
as many string in list. How to avoid that?

```
file1 = open("base.txt", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") 
Lines = file1.readlines()
file1.close()

not_needed = ['asd', '123', 'xyz']
row = 0

result = open("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
for line in Lines:
    for item in not_needed:
        if item not in line:
            row += 1
            result.write(str(row) + ": " + line)
```

so if the line contains the string from list, then delete it.
After every string print the file without the lines.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logic in your `for` loop... What it's doing is: take each line in `lines`, then for *all* the items in `not_needed` go through the line and write if condition is verified. But condition verifies each time the item is not found.
Try thinking about doing the inverse:

- check if a line is in non needed.
- if it is do nothing
- otherwise write it

Comment: i changed the `for line in Lines:` and `for item in not_needed` but still write as many string in NotNeeded

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/bsNQB3Qt) but how should i looks like?

Comment: You are still using the same logic as before. See below.

Answer (score 0):

**Expanded answer**:

Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
for line in Lines: 
   if item not in not_needed:
      row += 1
      result.write(str(row) + ": " + line)
```